# Is it possible to show the value of a variable in an assignment without using print()?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am using a Jupyter Notebook and I would like to find a method to display a variable assigned without using printf() or without having to write the variable name before running the cell.

I remember I saw somewhere that using '::' before the assignment would do the trick. But maybe it was in R. Is there anything similar in Python?

```
var1 = 3
:: var2 = var1 + 2
```

Output:
5

Comment: You could just run it in a REPL. Why are you avoiding using `print`?

Comment: I was looking for a quicker way to visualize my results. But I guess I will stick with `print`. Thanks.